# HttpContext no contiene una definición para Current

Tags: api, asp.net-core

Estoy siguiendo [este tutorial](https://enmilocalfunciona.io/construyendo-una-web-api-rest-segura-con-json-web-token-en-net-parte-ii/) que indica como levantar una API Rest sencilla con ASP.NET, el problema es que cuando llego a implementar la clase `TokenValidationHandler`, me dice que `HttpContext` no contiene una definición para `Current`.

```
// Extract and assign Current Principal and user
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out securityToken);
HttpContext.Current.User = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out securityToken); //No contiene definición.

return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
```

He visto en varias preguntas que pueden faltar algunas referencias o paquetes, pero tras intentar instalar varios de estos paquetes, ninguno me ha permitido definir el `Current.User` en `HttpContext`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
```

Comment: Aqui te lo explica, paso a paso que se debe hacer para utilizar el HttpContext
https://programmerclick.com/article/29861575716/